# Javascript error: Object required

Tags: javascript

The code below is some JavaScript which I have written.

It is showing an error on the marked line:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateOffpoint( )
    {
        var txt= document.getElementById('txtOffpoint')  
        if (txt.value.length<=3)
        {
            txt.focus()
            return;
        } 
        if (txt.value=="No Record Found" || txt.value=="")
        {
            txt.value=""
            txt.focus()
            return;
        }
    }

    function ConvertToUpperOffPoint()
    {  
        var txtOffpoint = document.getElementById("txtOffpoint"); 
        txtOffpoint.value = txtOffpoint.value.toUpperCase();     
    }

    function CheckTxtBox()
    {       
        strTextBoxVal = document.getElementById('txtOffpoint');
// ############################ Error in next line ############################
        strOrigin = Session("LocCode")

        if(strTextBoxVal.value.length > 0 )
        {
            if(strTextBoxVal.value.length < 3 )
            {
                lblErrMsg.innerText = "Flight Offpoint should not be less than 3 characters";
                strTextBoxVal.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (strTextBoxVal.value.substring(0,3) == strOrigin)
        {
            lblErrMsg.innerText = "Origin and Flight OffPoint cannot be the same.";
            strTextBoxVal.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(strTextBoxVal.value=="" )
        {
            if (document.getElementById("hdnHandled").value=="true")
            {
                lblErrMsg.innerText = "Flight Offpoint is required field for Handled Airline.";
                strTextBoxVal.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }

        lblErrMsg.innerText = "";
        return  validateFlightNo();
    }
</script>
```

Please, help me out. :-(

Comment: Missing semicolon at the end. Also, where is `Session` defined?

Comment: @Jon: Semicolons are optional.

Comment: In this case, JavaScript won't care that there is no semicolon. (although it's recommended that you use one).

Comment: Please provide a bit more info. What and where does Session() come from?

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote what the Session object is responsible for (server side? - see second answer)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: The kids today show no respect for semicolons. What is the world coming to?

Comment: @Jon: You also seem to show no respect for the truth. :(

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Because something is doable it doesn't mean that it's a good idea to do it.

Comment: @Jon: I wholeheartedly agree. I recommend the use of semicolons at the end of every statement in Javascript. However, your leading comment seemed to imply that you thought it might be relevant to solving the problem, which isn't true!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I didn't mean it that way; just wrote down what came into mind in the order in which it did. Guess I 've been honing the semicolon reflex a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing server side code with client side code.
Change the function to:

```
function CheckTxtBox()
    {     

      strTextBoxVal = document.getElementById('txtOffpoint');
      strOrigin = "<%=Session("LocCode")%>";
      if(strTextBoxVal.value.length > 0 )
      {
        if(strTextBoxVal.value.length < 3 )
        {
            lblErrMsg.innerText = "Flight Offpoint should not be less than 3 characters";
            strTextBoxVal.focus();
            return false;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

my Guess is that the constructor Session exists and you meant to use:

```
strOrigin = new Session("LocCode")
```